# Print a list from input file to the screen

Tags: java

```
Vegetable   Fruit       Desert
Carrot      banana       cake
Cucumber    apple       ice cream
Lettuce     orange      cookies 
Broccoli    grapes      donuts
```

I was wondering if there was a specific way to write a program so that only the fruit list is stored in an array list from an input file. So, basically what I want it to do is is print this to the screen: 
[image]

So, this is what I have so far and I honestly cannot figure out where to go from here. Anything would be appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String line;  
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        String filename = "list.txt";
        File inputFile = new File(filename);
        Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
        FileReader file = new FileReader(inputFile);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        line = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            if(line.equals("Vegetable   Fruit       Desert")){
                break;
            }
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            names.add(line);
        }
        in.close();
        reader.close();       
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating both a `Scanner` and a `BufferedReader`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split the lines and store the second element, which is fruit element. I've modified code in your second while loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String line;

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    String filename = "list.txt";
    File inputFile = new File(filename);
    FileReader file = new FileReader(inputFile);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
    // remove first line
    line = reader.readLine();

    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
        String[] words = line.split("\\t+");
        names.add(words[1]);
    }

    System.out.println(names);

    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: That will only print the first line of the input file which is:                
Vegetable Fruit  Desert

Comment: [cake, cream,  orange  cookies ,  grapes  donuts]
It printed this to the screen.

Comment: works fine on my computer. print your txt file out instead of showing an image. maybe your txt file's formatting problem leads to this.

Comment: @bacon9 Im thinking maybe you are using tab not space. modified the code. you can try it out

Comment: Yes,  I am using tab instead of a space. However, this code outputs [banana, ice cream, orange, grapes]. How exactly are you formatting your input file?

Comment: I use spaces. can you send me your txt? wongzeonbong@gmail.com

Comment: I've modified again to make it for tab. tested it locally and works. please try it out

Comment: glad that I can help : )